# What Does /**/or/**/ Mean?

Tags: security

We've logged get requests where someone tried to add `/**/or/**/` to the query string.

What does it mean, where can it do damage and what should I look out for in my code?

**Edit**

Specifically `/**/or/**/1=@@version)--` - what would that be targeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly an attempt at a [SQL Injection Attack](http://bobby-tables.com) or something very similar. It's easiest to think (and read) about this kind of vulnerability in terms of SQL, even if it's a slightly different attack vector in your case.

The idea is that if you've got SQL of this kind:

```
"SELECT User from USERS where UserName =" + user + " AND PASSWORD = " + password
```

then inserting values like the one you've seen directly into the SQL can cause the query to mean something entirely different (and typically laxer) than you expect. Normally SQL injection attacks contain single quotes though, to terminate text values within SQL. Are you sure the attacks you've seen *don't* have single quotes?

If you use parameterized SQL throughout your application (and no dynamic SQL within your database), and never try to use incoming user-specified values as "code" of any kind, you should be okay.

I suspect in your case it may *not* be SQL that the attacker expects to use to penetrate your security; it may well be Javascript. The idea is the same though: if you use any user input as "code" in some form, e.g. by building a string mixing that with predefined code, then execute that code, you're leaving yourself vulnerable to attack. Always treat code as code (under *your* control) and data as data.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain a query saying `SELECT ... WHERE ... /**/or/**/1=1`?

Not the `1=1`, that's an example, it's the way the `or` is surrounded that interests me.

Comment: Great answer, can you address the edit in the question as well?

Comment: @JNF: I've edited to make it clear that this may well not be an *actual* SQL injection attack, but something very similar aimed at (say) Javascript. Fundamentally I suspect it's someone trying to provided dodgy data in the hope that you'll execute it as code.

Comment: the edit looks like the one who is injecting wants to know the sql version. most probably to do more specific attacks next.

Comment: @JNF: What risingDarkness said, basically :) It still looks slightly odd to me, but I think it's increased the chance that it's an attempted SQL injection attack. I suspect the `/**/or/**/` is to terminate any comments which are within the "real" SQL - if you embed the user data *within a comment* then the data will terminate the comment early...

Comment: Thank you very much!
[:)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafasta_meruba_lo_tafasta)